# Lightning Community: Current User ID as URL Parameter

Tags: community, lightning-community, urlhacking, parameters, user-record

In a Lightning Community, is it possible to reference the current user's contact ID as a URL parameter? I want to link directly to the community user's contact record so they can update their contact information.

Alternatively, it would be nice to reference the user's ID or other user fields in the standard components, For example, if I'm using tiles and want to go directly to the Record Detail page and pre-fill the user's ID.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party. From what I can find these are all not available in Digital Experiences. Here is a link of all the parameters I found that are available.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.siteforce_communities_data_code_reference.htm&type=5

Comment: Could you reproduce the information from that link here? Links tend to change/become invalid over time, and fewer clicks is better UX.

Comment: I used the firstName field and the accountId field, these worked for me. They seem to be case sensitive.
Edit: I now understand the question as regarding links in the Navigation: there this didn't work for me. I ended up using /profile/home to navigate to the user page and show relevant information there. So I did not test these values in any URLs.